# Help identifying a story about a modern soldier serving reborn egyptian gods

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a novel when I was a child about a present day soldier, who I believe was a member of the SAS serving reborn egyptian gods who through guile overthrew all major religions.

There was a priest who used magic/whatever to control a wooden saqqara bird.

The soldiers all have vaguely magic weapons as well as rifles.

I'm fairly certain it was published in the 90s, and the cover was just a pyramid and the sun. The protagonist was a commanding officer and was seperated from his squad early in the novel. The gods appeared as characters and interacted with each other. Thats really all I can remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[The Age of Ra](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6484173-the-age-of-ra)*

[image: Book cover]

> The Ancient **Egyptian gods have defeated all the other pantheon**s and claimed dominion over the earth, dividing it into warring factions. Lt. David Westwynter, a **British soldier**, stumbles into Freegypt, the only place to have remained independent of the gods' influence. There, he encounters the followers of a humanist leader known as the Lightbringer, who has vowed to rid mankind of the shackles of divine oppression. As the world heads towards an apocalyptic battle, there is far more to this freedom fighter than it seems...

Reviews mention that he serves Osiris and Ra. The priests use wooden birds to do reconnaissance. They carry magical weapons empowered by the gods' *Ba*. The big catch? The book came out in 2009, so unless you were a child 7 years ago...

Comment: Thank you so much!

I thought it was a much older series, probably based on the condition of the book.

And I was 13 when I read it :P

Comment: This is like a combination of Dan Simmons' Ilium and Stargate...